# Ring commutative with a 1

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have seen in a book Commutative Algebra by Reid mention of a "ring commutative with a 1". Does that mean that addition and multiplication are commutative **and** that the multiplicative identity is 1 or it means that it is in some way commutative with respect to 1? Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a ring, addition is always commutative, and therefore when we talk about commutative rings, what that means is that multiplication is commutative. If we add that the ring has a $1$, what that means is that the ring has an identity element with respect to multiplication (denoted by $1$).

Comment: Why explicitly state that it has a 1 when even for it to be a ring it needs to have a 1?

Comment: Not for all authors.

Comment: So there are authors that consider an object with no multiplicative identity a ring?

Comment: Yes. Joseph Gallian, for instance. See his *Contemporary Abstract Algebra*.

Comment: I have read a bit and the following is confusing: "A unity (or identity) in a ring is a nonzero element that  is  an  identity  under  multiplication.  A  nonzero  element  of  a  commutative ring with unity need not have a multiplicative inverse. When it does, we say that it is a unit of the ring. Thus, $a$ is a unit if $a^-1$ exists." Is unity an identity under multiplication($1$) or an element that has a multiplicative inverse? It looks as though he is talking about one and the same thing.

Comment: An unit in a ring is an element which has a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: I first learned of rings long ago and I did not learn that they needed to have a multiplicative identity. It was many years later that I discovered that some consider it to be required.